# Overlapping anchor points of a compound path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

I have a compound path which I am trying to edit so that I have a closed path. However, when I drag the anchor point over a part of the compound path, the overlapping portion gets negated and becomes white. How do I fix this?[image]

Answer (score 6):

You need to change the fill rule of the compound path. An even-odd fill rule will give you the effect you're seeing whereas a non-zero winding fill rule uses path direction to determine the fill. You can change both fill rule and path direction from the Attributes panel.

[image]

It's not clear from your screenshot if you have a single path or multiple paths making up the compound path; if it's a single path then simply set the fill rule to non-zero winding (the left of the far right buttons). If there are multiple paths then you may *also* need to set all path directions to the same (hit either of the middle buttons).

You can read more here:

- [Adobe Illustrator Help – Apply fill rules to compound paths](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/combining-objects.html#apply_fill_rules_to_compound_paths)

Comment: @Radhika If that helped, don't forget to come back and choose this as the best answer!